# Sorting items by a string value and a numerical value, in different directions (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have this array of objects:

```js
 var items=  [{
          id: "rev-ar",
          qty: 13,
          effect: [{
           id: "after",
           value: 3}]
        }, {
          id: "rev-plu",
          qty: 2,
          effect: [{
           id: "rev",
           value: 1}]
        }];
//I want to sort it out first by name and then by effect.value so I did this:
var sorted = items.sort((a, b) => { //best revival items
       if(a.id == b.id) {
        return a.effect[0].value - b.effect[0].value;
       } else {
          return a.id - b.id;
       }
            }).filter(m => { return m.id.match('rev-'); });
        
        console.log(sorted);
```

this outputs rev-ar first but I want to reverse the order so rev-plu comes first so I did this:

```
return a.id - b.id;
```

but still no change in the order. Why is that?

Comment: Simply reverse your `a`s and `b`s.

Comment: `return b.id.localeCompare(a.id);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are subtracting the id's, but they aren't numbers

What you have written, `a.x - b.x`, works for a property `x`, *if* that property is a number. But here, `id` is a *string*!

#### To compare strings try this:

```
 return a.id.localeCompare(b.id);
```

and the reverse is:

```
 return b.id.localeCompare(a.id);
```